# Bookmarklet for saving Research Citations

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a browser bookmarklet that lets a user save a quotation (block of text) - and with the press of the bookmarklet - will save the quote, along with a timestamp and URL to their profile inside a web app.

You can see the code I've written below, but running into a few problems.

1. Wrapping the code nicely to work in a bookmarklet.
2. Obviously using the $post may be heavy given some pages will require it to be added by the bookmarklet.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

You can see where I'm at currently here http://jsfiddle.net/Rh7zx/1/

```
   (function() {
    function getSelectionHtml() {
    var html = "";
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var container = document.createElement("div");
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
            }
            html = container.innerHTML;
        }
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
        if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
            html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
        }
    }
    return html;
}

function saveToBiblio() {

    var url = window.location;
    var dateSaved = new Date();
    var selectedText = getSelectionHtml();

    console.log(url + dateSaved + selectedText);

    /*
    do the $post here
    */
}
)();
```

Comment: *"Obviously using the $post may not work cross browser."* It'll work just fine cross-browser, but it won't work on pages that don't have jQuery loaded, and it would be quite heavyweight for the bookmarklet to add jQuery to the page just for this.

Comment: Ah, sorry for that - you're quite right. So I just need to include jquery if its not loaded already?

Comment: Also slightly unsure how to use both these functions in the bookmarklet. Should I wrap into one?

Comment: @ user: I wouldn't load jQuery into a page that didn't have it loaded, no.

Comment: Seems like the `google-chrome-extension` and `jquery` tags are rather irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Wrapping the code nicely to work in a bookmarklet.

A bookmarklet is just JavaScript code encoded into a URL using the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol. There are several sites and tools that will take your code and turn it into a bookmarklet. The fundamental thing is to make it so that when the code is run, the thing you want to do occurs. Your code currently defines two functions, but doesn't *call* either of them. You'd want to call the relevant one. It's also generally best to wrap your bookmarklet code in a scoping function so you don't add to the page's global namespace (because of the possibility of conflicts):

```
(function() {
    // Your code here
)();
```

Some of the bookmarklet makers may have an option to do that for you, but doing it yourself is trivial.

> 2) Obviously using the $post may not work cross browser.

That will work fine cross-browser, but won't work in pages that don't have jQuery loaded, and loading jQuery into the page is probably overkill. I'd use `XMLHttpRequest` directly.

Comment: That's right, sorry to annoy you, but shouldn't I call the functions when the bookmarklet is clicked/script loaded?

Comment: @user2656127: Yes. **All** of your code will only run when the bookmarklet is triggered. None of it will run before the bookmarklet is triggered.

Comment: @user2656127: If you want to add to your question, edit the question and add the code there.

Comment: @user2656127: If you want to add to your question, add **the code** to the question. Off-site links are an optional adjunct, not a substitute.